# Conditional Rails Views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation, erb

The code below is fast becoming a common theme in my rails app. I have a bunch of conditions in my view for handling empty data, as well as, managing the push and pull of my grid. This will only grow as I begin to add the 3 other status's. My questions is this. What is the best way of managing my grid elegantly either in the view or controller so my views don't become increasingly bloated with conditions?

```
<% if @jobs.where(status: 'published').size == 0 %>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="large-12 columns">
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
<% if @jobs.where(status: 'published').size == 1 %> 
  <div class="row">
    <div class="large-4 push-8 columns">

    </div>
  </div>
<% elsif @jobs.where(status: 'published').size == 2 %>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="large-4 push-4 columns">
    </div>
  </div>
<% else %>
  <% @jobs.in_groups_of(3, false) do |row| %>
    <div class="row">
      <% for job in row %>
        <div class="large-4 medium-4 columns">

        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
 <% end %>
```

Comment: this is where you should begin to introduce presenters

Comment: @apneadiving thanks for commenting! Can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: check this: https://github.com/drapergem/draper

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use switch case statement for managing multiple conditions.

```
 @status = @jobs.where(status: 'published').size

<% case @status %>
 <% when 0 %>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="large-12 columns">
    </div>
  </div>
 <% when 1 %>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="large-4 push-8 columns">
    </div>
  </div>
 <% when 2 %>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="large-4 push-4 columns">
    </div>
  </div>
 <% else %>
  <% @published_jobs.in_groups_of(3, false) do |row| %>
    <div class="row">
      <% for job in row %>
        <div class="large-4 medium-4 columns">

        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for posting mate. I've looked into @apneadiving comments using presenters and I think it's a more elegant solution for my problem. It also reduces view bloat significantly.